# Why do some websites (like facebook) load scripts in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Why do some websites (like facebook) load scripts in an iframe?

Is this to allow the site to load more than 2 resources at a time because the iframe's resources are at different URLs?

Comment: For the record, Gmail does the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are seing, might be an application of "Comet" communication, using a hidden iframe as data channel. A short explanation of the technique according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)):

> A basic technique for dynamic web application is to use a hidden IFrame HTML element (an inline frame, which allows a website to embed one HTML document inside another). This invisible IFrame is sent as a chunked block, which implicitly declares it as infinitely long (sometimes called “forever frame”). As events occur, the iframe is gradually filled with script tags, containing JavaScript to be executed in the browser. Because browsers render HTML pages incrementally, each script tag is executed as it is received.

This could be used for something like a chat, where messages are expected to appear without noticeable delay, and preferably without periodical "polling" for new data. If this is what you have come across, you should see several `<script>` elements in the frame, and more should be added as times go by.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT**

So to actually address your question... I don't know! The following information might be helpful, however:

Facebook prepends all of the JS variables and functions with your application ID.

```
var ID;
```

becomes

```
var 1262682068026-ID;
```

This limits the scope of your javascript to only your application so you can't use the DOM to get at their friends, phone number, email, address, etc, unless authorized. It makes a little sub-sandbox for you to play in.

More info on scoping here:
[Facebook Docs](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/FBJS)

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: SLaks the purpose is to make a sandbox

Comment: How is 123-ID a valid variable name? think you mean 123_ID. You should update.

Answer (score 1):

javascript loaded in iframe have no access to parent page objects (cross-domain restriction)

Comment: Being a "cross-domain restriction", this would only apply if the iframe is from a different domain than the parent page, right?

Comment: See my answer: I don't know if the different domains restrict access to the parent page, but they do it explicitly anyways be appending each function/variable with a unique # to effectively sandbox them

Answer (score 1):

They load comet (aka comet, HTTP Push, long-lived, etc) connections in an iFrame because Internet Explorer eventually drops it:

http://cometdaily.com/2007/10/25/http-streaming-and-internet-explorer/

As it is effectively a continuous long poll, this is a blocker, this hack also increases IE's 2 connection limit leading to better responsiveness, background info:

http://alex.dojotoolkit.org/2006/02/what-else-is-burried-down-in-the-depths-of-googles-amazing-javascript/